# Can't connect to Linux update server using apt-get

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, apt

I am running Lubuntu 15.04 in VirtualBox and suddenly when I use the `apt-get` command it is unable to connect to the server I have been using for downloads (`ubuntuarchive.mirror.nac.net`). The problem has persisted for several days but I was previously able to install through `sudo apt-get`. Any suggestions?

The error message I get when I try to run `sudo apt-get update` is versions of this for every package:

```
Failed to fetch http://ubuntuarchive.mirror.nac.net/dists/wily/Release.gpg Unable to connect to ubuntuarchive.mirror.nac.net:http:
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you perform the usual networking troubleshooting steps? Connect from outside the VM, connect from inside the VM using curl or ping, test DNS lookup, etc., etc...

Answer (score 2):

Most likely that mirror is dead. It makes sense since Ubuntu 15.10 was [end-of-lifed on July 28, 2016](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). Meaning no more patches and no more upgrades. Your best and most solid bet is to moving to an LTS of Ubuntu such as Ubuntu 16.04; or Lubuntu 16.04 in your case.

But if you want to get a final round of patches in place, you can change your `sources.list` to point to the Ubuntu `old-releases` archive. Instructions [can be found here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades).

First, back up your `sources.list` like this:

sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.BACKUP

Then open up your `sources.list` file like this:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And replace the contents with this:

```
## EOL upgrade sources.list
# Required
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-security main restricted universe multiverse

# Optional
#deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

And then run `update` like this:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And when that is done, you should be set… In some way.

But honestly, you should upgrade to 16.04 LTS to get out of this mess.